# Object.watch when delete property not worked

Tags: javascript

I have a problem .
My code :

```
var o = { p: 1 };

o.watch("p", function (id, oldval, newval) {
    console.log( "o." + id + " changed from " + oldval + " to " + newval );
    return newval;
});

o.p = 2;

o.p = 3;

delete o.p; 

o.p = 4; /* dont works */

o.p = 14;/* dont works */

o.unwatch('p');
o.p = 5;
```

I have a problem. When I remove a property Object.watch dont work ! Is there a way as to make it work then?

Another example :

```
var o = { p: 1 };

o.watch("root", function (id, oldval, newval) {
    console.log( "o." + id + " changed from " + oldval + " to " + newval );
    return newval;
});

delete o.root;
o.root = 2;  //dont works
```

But:

```
var o = { p: 1 };

o.watch("root", function (id, oldval, newval) {
    console.log( "o." + id + " changed from " + oldval + " to " + newval );
    return newval;
});

//delete o.root;
o.root = 2; //o.root changed from undefined to 2
```

Thank you very much ...

Comment: What version of the browser are you using? I tested the code in Aurora 32.0a2 (2014-07-21) and it works as expected (i.e. as described in the MDN reference - the watch listener keeps watching the changes even after the property had been deleted).